# Trigger scrollbar when container gets too small for table

Tags: html, css

The below div structure is placed within another framework of divs, that are flexible in terms of widths and heights.  I am trying to make the table scrollable when the outlying container becomes too small. The image is stretchable and will always be at the bottom, aspect will be maintained if the the area becomes wider/narrower, so the height will vary. The below html/css displays everything alright when there is plenty of room, however no scrollbars seem to be triggered as the area becomes smaller. The table can have a random number of rows, however if the height/width exceeds the space that has been dedicated externally, scrollbars should kick in. How do I get this to happen? I have read through similar questions posted here, however none of the suggestions seem to have any effect, absolutely no scrollbar show up, it looks like the table div just slides behind the image div instead of being "squeezed" above in the remaining space, when I try and grab it through the DOM element viewer in the browser debugger. I am guessing I need to specify height for both table and image div, however the image height can be anything, i.e. if I specify a percentage it might cause gaps, I tried using auto, however it does not seem to help.

HTML:

```
<div id="alldiv">
   <div id="areadiv">
      <table class="StandardTextStyle" border="0">
         <tbody>
            <tr>
               <td>Description:</td>
               <td>Processed Orders</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>Server Instance:</td>
               <td>dbServer\sql2016</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>Database Name:</td>
               <td>Orders</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>Owner:</td>
               <td>dbo</td>
            </tr>
         </tbody>
      </table>
   </div>
   <div id="logodiv">
      <img src="logo.png">
   </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#alldiv {
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
}

#logodiv img {
   width: 100%;
   position: absolute;
   bottom: 0;
   left: 0;
   height: auto;
}

#areadiv {
   overflow:auto;
   margin-top:20px;
   top: 0;
   height: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to achieve this:

### 1. Give up on `position:absolute` ...

for image and use `flex` with `flex-direction:column`. For this to work, the container (the cell in your grid system) has to have a set physical `height` (in this example I used `height:100vh` on `body` - which you shouldn't copy in your project, by the way):

```css
#alldiv {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#logodiv img {
  width: 100%;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
}
#logodiv img {
  float: left;
}
#areadiv {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  overflow:auto;
  margin-top:20px;
  top: 0;
  height: auto;
}

/* Do not copy the code below this line to your project! */
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<div id="alldiv">
   <div id="areadiv">
      <table class="StandardTextStyle" border="0">
         <tbody>
            <tr>
               <td>Description:</td>
               <td>Processed Orders</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>Server Instance:</td>
               <td>dbServer\sql2016</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>Database Name:</td>
               <td>Orders</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>Owner:</td>
               <td>dbo</td>
            </tr>
         </tbody>
      </table>
   </div>
   <div id="logodiv">
      <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=350%C3%97150&w=350&h=150" /></div>
</div>
```

### 2. ... or use `javascript`

on `window` `load` and `resize` events to change the `padding-bottom` of your grid cell container according to the current height of `<img>`. Considering the tags you placed on your question, I'm assuming you're not interested in this solution, but if you need, I can provide an example.